# Why is this method locking up my WPF UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, parallel-processing

I am running a recursive method, which uses dispatchers, and parallel processing to read music meta data. I am confused why it's locking up the UI. It doesn't matter whether I start the method on a new thread or not.

It locks up the UI for long periods, then it will update, lock up, and so on. I'd appreciate some input on how to prevent this. So far I have made the recursion use a lower priority (background). So the method runs on normal priority, and when it reaches each directory it calls itself with background priority (Meaning it will not call that recursion until the normal priority threads have finished.)

**Edit:** The method actually works fine for smaller numbers of files (Less than 1,000), but for larger directories (With upwards up 50,000 music files it displays this behavior.) The memory and cpu intensity seem fine. It doesn't run out of memory, and cpu usage is normal.

this method can be called like:

```
DirSearch("C:\MyMusicFolder\");
```

Here's the method:

```
private void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.mp3"), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, filename =>
            {

                try
                {
                   // filelist.Add(filename);

                    using (var mp3 = new Mp3File(filename))
                    {
                        Id3Tag tag = mp3.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.Version1x);
                        if (tag != null)
                        {
                            var listitem = new ArtistListItem();
                            listitem.Track = tag.Title;
                            listitem.Artist = tag.Artists;
                            listitem.Album = tag.Album;

                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                              DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
                              new Action(() => this.playlist.Items.Add(listitem)));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }

            });
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
            {
                DirSearch(path);
            }));

        }
    }));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blocks the UI thread because it does not happen on another thread.

Regardless how yo ustart it, it is cluttered with (actually redundant) calls back into the UI thread.

> Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(

is right there in the first line.

There is no need for any of those EXCEPT the one do add the items to the playlist, as far as I can see.